# Can we deploy MVC 4 application on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, asp.net-mvc-2

I have got a new task to convert mvc 2.0 application into mvc 4.0 using razor engine. Currently MVC 2.0 applicaion is hosted on Window Server 2003 and IIS 6.

My question is, Can we use the same enviroment for mvc 4.0 application or should we need to upgrade the IIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow these steps

1. Open IIS Manager, expand the master server node (i.e, the Servername node), and then select the Web service extensions node.
2. In the right pane of IIS Manager, right-click the extension "ASP.NET v4.0.*".
3. Click the Allow button.

Comment: I have an MVC 4 app installed to our IIS 6 Dev Server running on Windows Server 2003 SP2. We have .NET 2 SP2, .NET 3 SP2, .NET 3.5 SP1, .NET 4 Client Profile, and .NET 4 Extended installed on the server. Vijai Singh recommended this helpful link to me when I asked a similar question: [link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx/)

Comment: This is it! every one is explaining the obvious (adding the wildcard) but no one mentions this! gold you actually saved me a lot of work!