# Why does Entity Framework with Windows Authentication not pass my credentials to SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-5, iis-6, windows-authentication

I'm trying to get an MVC 4 intranet site with Entity Framework 5 working on web server running IIS6 but Windows Authentication/Integrated Security is not working right because the error says

> **Stack Trace:**
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user
>   'EASTDOMAIN\WEBDEV2$'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5104926
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +260
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +2294
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) +35
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   withFailover) +250
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance,
>   SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   TimeoutTimer timeout) +932
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection
>   owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString
>   connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>   +195    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo,
>   String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean
>   redirectedUserInstance) +316
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningConnection) +185
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>   +33    System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +524
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +66
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject) +479
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +108
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +85
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +341
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +258
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +34
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +163
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +41
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting
>   provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity
>   Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is
>   correct.]
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +166
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +40
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +46
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +62
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +117
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +453    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +18
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +56
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
>   +18    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +73    System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1
>   source, String path) +85
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source,
>   Expression`1 path) +126
>
>   Reclosing.Controllers.RecloserController.Index() +198
>
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +17
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
>   +59    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
>   +240    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +31
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +128    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +26
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +25    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +25    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +25    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +30    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9042429    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1016

**Here is my web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
    -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
             <add name="ReclosingContext" connectionString="Data Source=sqlserverbox\devtest;Initial Catalog=Reclosing;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
            <remove name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
                        <add name="cshtml-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.cshtml, *." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        </handlers>
                <defaultDocument>
                        <files>
                                <add value="index.aspx" />
                        </files>
                </defaultDocument></system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    </entityFramework>
        <location path="Web.config">
                <system.web>
                        <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" />
                </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```

**'EASTDOMAIN\WEBDEV2$' is not my UserID, but is the domain\servername.** 
I've tried playing around with adding an impersonate to the config to no avail. This worked fine in IIS Express on my local PC connecting to the same SQL 2005 DB (which is on its own box). My local PC runs Windows 7 using VS2012.

I'm new to this so if anyone can help, I could really use it! I'm getting tired of beating my head against the wall!

Comment: You haven't specified any credentials to send. So `Integrated Security=SSPI` will log on as whatever user is running. If you're hosting it in IIS, then it's probably running as a service and it's "the computer account". IIS Express would have been running not as a service, but as you. Configure the application pool to log on as a user then give that user permissions to the database. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=iis+access+sql+server

Comment: Thanks for your comment ta.speot.is; Your comment clarifies what I suspected.

Answer (score -2):

One of the server guys at work pointed me to this link which is a helpful reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

He and others discouraged me from using Windows Authentication. One reason was that I would start having to add each new user as an account to the database and it could become very cumbersome with a large user base. Also, in our environment where we have the potential for users coming from different log in domains, then the issues with having the correct trusts and authentication paths between domains comes into play.

So I stopped trying to use Windows Authentication to connect to the database, and created a single log on account in the database for EF in the MVC application to use (from the web server to the DB server). It works great this way, however, I'll have to set up some sort of database table to track and authorize which users have read/write access to the main data vs all the read-only users (who won't be in that table).

My connection string changed to have this connection string:

```
<add name="ReclosingContext" connectionString="Data Source=sqlserverbox\devtest;Initial Catalog=Reclosing;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**I thought Windows Authentication\Integrated Security would make things simpler and better for the users for the entire application, but found that in our environment, it is better not to use it for the SQL Server connection.**

Comment: -1 Does not answer the question, not does it indicate that the request is impossible.  There are many corporate environments where the developer and admins have complete control of the AD structure, and it is reasonable to add users to AD Groups that have DB access.